# How to use multiple custom View Controllers with a Navigation Controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Basically, I have two view controllers inside the MainWindow.xib that can be viewed by clicking the Bar Button in my Navigation Controller. I wanted those two view controllers to be separated from the MainWindow.xib with their own header, implementation and xib files and still make Navigation Controller inside of MainWindow.xib work in them.

To better understand it, please see the codes below:

Thanks a lot!

**TestAppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface TestAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
    {
        //Navigation Controller
        IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;


        //View Controllers
        UIViewController *viewController;
        UIViewController *viewController2;
        UIViewController *viewController3;

    }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

    //Navigation Controller
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;


    //View Controllers
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIViewController *viewController;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIViewController *viewController2;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIViewController *viewController3;


    - (IBAction)next;
    - (IBAction)next2;


    @end
```

**TestAppDelegate.m**

```
#import "TestAppDelegate.h"

@implementation TestAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

//Navigation Controller
@synthesize navigationController;

//View Controllers
@synthesize viewController;
@synthesize viewController2;
@synthesize viewController3;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    //Navigation Controller
    [self.window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{

}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{

}

- (void)dealloc
{

    [viewController release];
    [viewController2 release];
    [viewController3 release];

    [navigationController release];
    [_window release];
    [super dealloc];
}


- (IBAction)next {
    [navigationController pushViewController:viewController2 animated:YES];
}


- (IBAction)next2 {
    [navigationController pushViewController:viewController3 animated:YES];
}


@end
```

**Inside MainWindow.xib:**

http://i52.tinypic.com/10xa45f.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally don't touch `MainWindow.xib`. I suggest the following:

1. Create a `MainController` which will be your MainView that subclass `UIViewController` by going to `File > New > New File`. That will create a .h/.m and nib file for each ViewController. There add whatever UI you want for your app. For Example, add two buttons and wire those buttons to `IBActions` in your MainController. This should be declared and implemented in your `MainController.{h/m}`, respectively.
2. After that create another two ViewControllers, the same way.
3. The body of those IBActions should create an instance of the your ViewControllers and then push them.

It would look something like this:

```
YourViewController *yvc = [[YourViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yvc animated:YES];
[yvc release];
```

Finally, you have to push the MainController in your `AppDelegate` and add your `NavigationController` to the view.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
     MainViewController *mvc = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
     UINavigationController *unvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
     [unvc pushViewController:mvc animated:NO];
     [mvc release];
     [self.window addSubview:unvc.view];
     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
     return YES;
 }
```

Comment: LOL. I stepped out for 5 mins mid-answer and ended up posting the same   approach Can offered. Sorry about that.

Comment: It's OK. I appreciate your comments. Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: Hi. With the two new view controllers created, what code will I put in it that I created inside the TestAppDelegate.h and TestAppDelegate.m above? Also, where will I put the IBActions code you created above? Will I just edit the code at TestAppDelegate.m or put it in the implementation files of my two new view controllers?

Comment: I'll edit my answer to give you more information. Also I suggest you check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296695/beginning-iphone-development-in-xcode-4/7296894#7296894) I posted a great resource for beginners iPhone developers.

Comment: Also, this [project](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/system/files/sample_code/Vocabulous.zip) is a good example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks. I actually downloaded all those Stanford iTunes U videos but haven't watched it yet because of this app that needs immediate completion. :( If you could provide me with a short completed project with one custom view controller controlled by a navigation controller, that'd be great! RE: Stanford project link, I'm downloading it now and will check on it. I totally apologize for the noob questions.

Comment: This is actually what I want to achieve: http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/display-the-newview-after-pressing-button/ but the code and tutorial doesn't use a navigation controller like I wanted so I won't need to create the back button since the navigation controller automatically creates it.

Comment: Ok I saw what you want to accomplish. I think you should be set with my last edit to the answer and that project. Still, I encourage you to view that course is extremely resourceful.

Comment: Thanks. Will definitely watch that after I make this app work. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Set the "class" property in Interface Builder (third tab in the inspector, "*Custom Class*") to the name of the custom class you're planning to use, and then put the name of the .xib file you want to load from in the "NIB Name" (fourth tab).

The code you're using to push the viewController is alright. Make sure to never accidentaly dealloc any of the two UIViewController.

Speaking of which, keep in mind that this approach is keeping the ViewControllers always in memory, even when not in use. Another approach is to completely remove the IBOutlets for the two ViewControllers, and do something like:

```
- (IBAction)next
{
    MyCustomViewController *customViewController = [[MyCustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:<#NibName or nil#> bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; 
    [navigationController pushViewController:customViewController animated:YES];
    [customViewController release];
}
```

This creates the object when needed (If I remember right, the UI elements from the xib are cached somewhere, so that may be irrelevant[citation needed]). Just something to keep in mind, depending on the frequency of use of your two ViewControllers.

Comment: Thanks a lot Can! I appreciate it! I'll try to implement this in my app. :D

Comment: Hi. I can't seem to make it work. :( Is it possible to send me a link to a complete project instead or if you can find a nice tutorial for me to read on, can you post it here? Thanks!